# unit test - recompile only around "int main()" to reduce compilation time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

A project in my Visual Studio solution can be divided into :-

```
Library.h, Library.cpp
User.h, User.cpp  (#include Library.h)
Main.h, Main.cpp  (#include User.h)  has "int main()"
```

*(The real project is far bigger than this.)*

Whenever I edit any `Library.h` file and press `F5`, it will recompile the whole project.     It makes sense.

Now I want to code/debug `Library` and test it alone, and I don't want to recompile everything because it costs more time.

Therefore :-

- I created `Main2.cpp` that `#include` only `Library.h`, and have no code involving `User` at all.
- I commented out the whole `main.cpp`.

Here is my **main2.cpp** :-

```
#include "Library.h"
int main(){ .... some code about library ....}
```

When I press F5, it compiled all `.cpp` and run fine.   That still makes sense.

### Problem

If I edited `Library.h`, and press F5 again, it will recompile :-

- `library.cpp`
- `User.cpp`    <--- no!
- `main.cpp`    <--- no!
- `main2.cpp`

### Question

How to make Visual Studio recompile only necessary files to save compilation time?
(compile only `library.cpp` and `main2.cpp` in this case)

I guess the need to recompile a lot of files is that there may be some static function inside `User` that **do something** about `library`.

What if I know for sure that there are not?
Even if there is **something**, I want to (risk) ignore it.

Comment: If you have a library, create an actual library project that contains just the library.

Comment: @n.m.  Thank, the god n.m. Useful comment as always.  I am glad that you do not destroy my dream again with some horrific-but-always-correct comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate your solution into 3 projects:

- Library
- LibraryTests
- Main

When you don't want to re-compile 'Main', just right-click it and unload the project.

You should probably look to break up Library.h into smaller pieces, so that the dependencies are more self-contained.

Comment: You mean .... if I have  10 separate test that I want to compile individually, I have to create 21 projects?  (2*n+1)    .....  (Thank for the "unload"!)  .... Do you mean recommend "static-library"?

Comment: No. They don't need breaking down _that_ small; keep them cohesive.

Comment: Compiling an individual C++ file shouldn't be that slow. If you're really worried about the time it takes, C++ compilers are slow, but they're not usually *that* slow. You might have other issues making your compiles take too long. Look at precompiled headers; get an SSD; buy a copy of "Large-Scale C++ Software Design" by John Lakos.

Comment: "Do you mean recommend "static-library"?" -- depends on your project. Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: If not, what type of project I should create, roughly base on the question?  (I am very new to "new project")  ..... or Win32 can be OK, if my project is already Win32?   Should I use some special type?

Comment: No need to unload anything. If you want to build just the test project, there's a menu item for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend instead of suffering headache with visual studio to download the [MinGW](http://mingw.org) c++ compiler for Windows and just compile a smaller unit-test instance of the files which you need as a sort of different project all together in with the console.

Comment: Apart from another headache from changing tool, it is also (a little?) hard  because "Library" actually include a lot of external libraries (a lot of `additional include directory`+`dll` bind setting).  With Visual Studio, I can profile / debug-watch.  It is an environment that I am accustomed to.

Comment: In that case you can right click on the files in solution explorer, and select the option exclude from build, but for your larger project it's could be painful. Unless you just disable your main.cpp function from the build then main2.cpp takes over and as long as you're not calling methods that you don't want to call from other cpp/h files there shouldn't be any worry.

Comment: If you make changes to a single cpp file it will only compile that file where as if you make changes to a header file, all files in which it's included will be recompiled. So you could try moving the header into a different dir then including it with the different directory or make a copy under a different name?

Comment: "exclude from build" <-- I can't do it to many filters at once. "Include" they back is also hard.  ....  "changes to a single cpp file"<--  Sometimes there are change in `Library.h`.  In that case, I wish `User.cpp` should not be recompiled because `Library.h` is not `#include` in `main.cpp` (or at least there should be an option that easy to set).

Comment: Then there's not really any way other than doing what we've already discussed. Unless you're fine with creating a visual studio project for Unit testing purposes.